Calling Files.copy() fails because of enum
I am trying to call a Java method in Saxon XSLT.  I can successfully call methods such as File.renameTo(), but Files.copy() fails because of the enum.
Here's the XSLT:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:files="java:java.nio.file.Files" xmlns:path="java:java.nio.file.Path" xmlns:copyopt="java:java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption" exclude-result-prefixes="files path copyopt" version="3.0" expand-text="yes">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:if test="files:copy(path:of(xs:anyURI('file:///from.txt')),path:of(xs:anyURI('file:///to.txt')),copyopt:REPLACE_EXISTING)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

The error is:

There is more than one method matching the function call Q{java:java.nio.file.Files}copy#3, and there is insufficient type information to determine which one should be used

Any suggestions in how to type the enum REPLACE_EXISTING properly?

Shouldn't copyopt:REPLACE_EXISTING rather be copyopt:REPLACE_EXISTING()? But I am not sure that will solve it. Does the -TJ option show the different method overloads between it can't decide?

Of course, if you have access to reflexive Java extension functions you also have access to EXPath file functions like https://www.saxonica.com/documentation12/index.html#!functions/expath-file/copy so perhaps this task can be solved by using that function instead of fighting with the reflexive overload problem.

copyopt:REPLACE_EXISTING() doesn't resolve the issue

Yes, expath file:copy() works, and is simpler.  I forgot about expath.  And so had chatgpt and grok.  That's the downside of using AI too much.  That said, I would still like to know what I did wrong with the direct Java approach.  Something special needs to happen with typing of enums.

I am not sure it is the enum third parameter, there seem to be two three argument overloads of the copy method and somehow Saxon can't choose the one with the first two arguments being java.nio.file.Paths but also considers the overload with the first argument being an InputStream and the second argument being a Path a candidate. Perhaps Michael Kay can explain and resolve that.

I didn't run -TJ, as this is all embedded in a Java web service.  But oXygen reports the error as well.  The two method overloads I can see are copy​(InputStream in, Path target, CopyOption... options) and copy​(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)

I think with both the first two arguments being Paths it should be possible for Saxon to decide which overload to choose. But somehow it sees the overload with the InputStream first argument also as a candidate and thinks for both overloads "Arguments cannot be converted to required types". Not sure why that is, the only odd thing is perhaps the varargs CopyOption... options.

Firstly, the message "XPST0017  There is more than one method matching the function call Q{java:java.nio.file.Files}copy#3, and there is insufficient type information to determine which one should be used" is a little misleading in this case: using the -TJ option reveals that none of the candidate methods has suitable types.
So I tried changing the call on Files.copy#3 to a call on Files.move#3, which is very similar but does not have the overload. With a bit of adjustment, the following stylesheet works:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
  xmlns:files="java:java.nio.file.Files" xmlns:path="java:java.nio.file.Path" 
  xmlns:copyopt="java:java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="3.0" expand-text="yes">
    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <saxon:do action="files:move(
            path:of(xs:anyURI('file:///Users/.../temp/from1.txt')),
            path:of(xs:anyURI('file:///Users/.../temp/from2.txt')),
            copyopt:REPLACE_EXISTING())"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

(I used saxon:do here to force the extension function to be called despite the fact that its result is never used.)
So Saxon is handling the enum type and the varargs argument with copyopt:REPLACE_EXISTING() successfully if the method call is unambiguous, but when it has to do detailed type analysis to work out which of the two methods to call, it's finding neither of them suitable. Looking at the code, that's because the type analysis doesn't consider varargs: it establishes that an argument of type CopyOptions isn't assignable to the required type array of CopyOptions and doesn't take into account that with varargs, the call would actually work.

Thanks Michael.  So the net result is one cannot call Files:copy#3 in Saxon, correct?

I would be reluctant to say it's impossible, but I don't see an obvious way of doing it. Generally my approach is to define a Java wrapper over the functions you want to call, to give them an XPath-friendly interface (for example, identifying files by strings rather than Path objects).

Logged as an issue for future attention here: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/6621?issue_count=44&issue_position=1&next_issue_id=6611

It might be the varargs argument that throws Saxon off or that needs special coding, I have created a helper class using a single/normal argument option e.g.
package org.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.CopyOption;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Files;


public class FilesHelper {

    public static void copy(Path src, Path dest, CopyOption copyOption1) throws IOException {
        Files.copy(src, dest, copyOption1);
    }

}

then if I declare e.g. xmlns:filesHelper="java:org.example.FilesHelper" and use filesHelper:copy(path:of(xs:anyURI('file:///from.txt')),path:of(xs:anyURI('file:///to.txt')),copyopt:REPLACE_EXISTING()) Saxon EE (tested with 12.5) runs that code (of course with the compiled helper class on the classpath) without problems, using the helper method.
Although now I have rewritten the helper method to also use varargs
public class FilesHelper {

    public static void copy(Path src, Path dest, CopyOption... copyOption) throws IOException {
        Files.copy(src, dest, copyOption);
    }

}

and Saxon manages to select that method as well
Found a candidate method:
    public static void org.example.FilesHelper.copy(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption[]) throws java.io.IOException

so in the Files.copy resolution problem it might be a mix of having two three arguments overloads and varargs; I will keep this "answer" until we'll see some better explanation from Michael Kay or Saxonica, then I will probably have to delete it.
